# Chromecast MEDIA ELEMENT STALLED when streaming HLS with official sample

Tags: chromecast

When we tried using the latest media library 0.7.0 with the official sample, video stalls at the first frame.

The official sample is at //github.com/googlecast/CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM .

The link we tried is [http://9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2.m3u8](http://9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/_definst_/liveevent/live-ch1-2.m3u8) .

Is it something wrong with the HLS link?

Console Logs:

> [ 24.843s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":1,\"playbackRate\":1>,\"playerState\":\"BUFFERING\",\"currentTime\":0,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":1,\"muted\":false},\"media\":{\"contentId\":\"//9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/*definst*/>liveevent/live-ch1-2.m3u8\",\"streamType\":\"buffered\",\"contentType\":\"video/mp4\",\"duration\":null}}],\"requestId\":23248020}"}
>   cast_receiver.js:18
>   [ 24.667s] [cast.player.api.Player] loadedmetadata
>   media_player.js:24
>
> ### MEDIA ELEMENT DATA LOADED mpl.js:61
>
> {} mpl.js:103
>   [ 25.049s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.sample.mediaplayer","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"video_bitrates\":[0]}"}
>   cast_receiver.js:18
>
> ### MEDIA ELEMENT CAN PLAY mpl.js:129
>
> [ 24.882s] [cast.player.api.Player] play
>   media_player.js:24
>
> ### MEDIA ELEMENT PLAYING mpl.js:139
>
> [ 25.249s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/streams/livepkgr/events/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2Num505727.ts 200]
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 25.259s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager] 0: current=4195699.16, average=4789802.98
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 25.276s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] adjustTime: 8 : 7.822999954223633
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 25.278s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: append
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 25.531s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/streams/livepkgr/events/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2Num505728.ts -1]
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 25.536s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 24000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/streams/livepkgr/events/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2Num505728.ts -1]
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 25.542s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/streams/livepkgr/events/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2Num505728.ts -1]
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 25.560s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: 0 - 15.89799976348877
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 25.567s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: updateend
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 25.894s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Buffering state changed, isPlayerBuffering: false old time: 0 current time: 0.349
>   cast_receiver.js:18
>   [ 25.916s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message
>   cast_receiver.js:18
>   [ 25.929s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":1,\"playbackRate\":1>,\"playerState\":\"PLAYING\",\"currentTime\":0.349,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":1,\"muted\":false}}],\"requestId\":0}"}
>   cast_receiver.js:18
>   [ 26.543s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/streams/livepkgr/events/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2Num505728.ts 200]
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 26.548s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager] 0: current=6509453.83, average=5993558.58
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 26.554s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] adjustTime: 16 : 15.89799976348877
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 26.555s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: append
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 26.668s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: 0 - 23.839000701904297
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 26.673s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: updateend
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 26.908s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Buffering state changed, isPlayerBuffering: true old time: 0.349 current time: 0.349
>   cast_receiver.js:18
>   [ 26.909s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message
>   cast_receiver.js:18
>   [ 26.912s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":1,\"playbackRate\":1>,\"playerState\":\"BUFFERING\",\"currentTime\":0.349,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":1,\"muted\":false}}],\"requestId\":0}"}
>   cast_receiver.js:18
>
> ### MEDIA ELEMENT STALLED mpl.js:148
>
> [ 30.855s] [cast.player.hls.Playlist] update: //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2.m3u8
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 30.858s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2.m3u8 -1]
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 30.861s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2.m3u8 -1]
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 30.863s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2.m3u8 -1]
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 30.962s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2.m3u8 200]
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 30.982s] [cast.player.hls.Playlist] update in: 8000
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 38.995s] [cast.player.hls.Playlist] update: //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2.m3u8
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 39.002s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2.m3u8 -1]
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 39.009s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2.m3u8 -1]
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 39.012s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2.m3u8 -1]
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 39.083s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2.m3u8 200]
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 39.120s] [cast.player.hls.Playlist] update in: 8000
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 47.135s] [cast.player.hls.Playlist] update: //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2.m3u8
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 47.140s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2.m3u8 -1]
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 47.145s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2.m3u8 -1]
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 47.150s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2.m3u8 -1]
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 47.256s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET //9x9ch1.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/*definst*/liveevent/live-ch1-2.m3u8 200]
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 47.290s] [cast.player.hls.Playlist] update in: 8000
>   media_player.js:24
>   [ 47.295s] [cast.player.hls.PlaylistIterator] update: 505728 not found in new playlist

Thank you!

Comment: Seems like it is not a good playlist. Have you tried any other stream that is known to be good?

Comment: Thank you Ali! The link we tried is playable on desktop VLC and iOS player through mobile safari. Is there any possible mistake of the link?

Comment: A lot of streams do not follow the standards 100% ad different players have different level of forgiveness; so if one player (say VLC) is not complaining, it doesn't mean that the stream is 100% compliant. The MPL player is less forgiving compared to VLC.

Answer (score 0):

If I add CORS headers using [CORS proxy](http://www.corsproxy.com/) server everything seems fine to me. More info about CORS header / Google Cast is [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player?hl=en).